# is it possible to have a chaotic evil paladin?

Tags: dnd-5e, alignment, paladin

My party has a chaotic evil paladin in it. He is constantly trying to kill other members of the party and it's getting really annoying.

Is it even possible for him to be a chaotic evil paladin, according to the rules?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the cited question, so closure is appropriate. However, you've another inferred useful question relating to party dynamics and table etiquette, which I think you'll be well-served to create as it's own question.

Comment: A "chaotic evil paladin" is a moot question. You have a problem player — a player who "is constantly trying to kill other members of the party and it's getting really annoying". This is the problem to solve, it is not the class/alignment problem.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes

In 5th edition D&D, they removed the alignment restrictions you may recall from previous editions. While the Dungeon Master's Guide offers some options for even evil-er paladins, it's perfectly possible for a normal paladin to be chaotic evil. I'm looking at you, Oath of Vengeance.

Comment: A strict reading of an Oath sort of prevents the idea of someone who is chaotic from even getting to the point of taking, let alone keeping an oath. Every table I have played at for 5E, including my own limits Paladins to Lawful. Even the flavor text prior to the statistics alludes against it to be honest. This is correct strictly from a rules perspective though.

Comment: @Slagmoth While I wouldn't disallow this combination at my table, I'd have some serious questions for the player about it. I suppose the best reply I have is at the end of Creating a Paladin: "Your oath and alignment might be in harmony, or your oath might represent standards of behavior that you have not yet attained." You may not apply your oath consistently, opting to kill a child who threw a stone at you, while sparing a marauder to 'spread the word'.

Comment: It is true, unless you play Adventure League. CE characters are forbidden in the League.